# Want to get the change notification of the online meeting like meeting started/meeting ended in Microsoft Teams(Graph API)

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I am developing an application where I want to have the trigger when someone starts, end, the participant added, etc in the online meeting in Microsoft Teams.

For this, I tried by creating a subscription for the resource called `me/event` (This might not work for the online meeting). I am receiving the change notification trigger for when event created/deleted/updated but not when online meeting starts/ended/participantAdded etc.

I found that we can use delta link to get the changed data but I am looking for the process to get the exact notifications like meeting started/ended etc from MS Teams through Graph API.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Today Microsoft Graph change notifications do not support the online meeting resource. You might request that on [uservoice](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com). Depending on your scenario your might want to look at [Microsoft teams call meetings bots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/calls-and-meetings/calls-meetings-bots-overview)

Comment: ..to indirectly infer the statuses - are there any APIs around the number of participants that inform you if someone leaves from the online meeting?

Comment: The cloud communication APIs should help you with that https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/communications-api-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: Hi @baywed thank you for your reply. I have used cloud communications APIs, I believe that we can involve bots in creating a meeting. But can we receive when a participant leaves the active multiparty call?

Comment: From a Microsoft Graph Change notifications perspective not today, I suggest adding it to uservoice if you need it. From a bot framework perspective I don't know much about it and I think you should ask that as a separate question.

Comment: Requested on https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/40286245-change-notifications-on-online-meeting-apis

Comment: @Bijay Kushawaha Did you find any way to get notifications for meeting started,ended and participant joined? How did you achieve this?